# lists' recursive dividing F#

Tags: f#

it seems, I need help with my recursive function, it not applied. I have an example, but I don't understand what I must to do. where is my mistake? I will be glad to any help!

my function:

```
let rec split = function
  | [] -> ([],[])
  | [x] -> ([x], [])
  | x :: y :: tail -> split ((fun z -> z)(fun acc -> (x :: fst acc, y :: snd acc))) tail
let res = split [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
printfn "%A" res
```

example:

```
let rec split cont = function
  | [] -> cont ([],[])
  | [x] -> cont ([x], [])
  | x :: y :: tail -> split (fun acc -> cont (x :: fst acc, y :: snd acc)) tail
let res = split (fun x -> x) [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
printfn "%A" res
```

Comment: What's the problem? You've just posted two different pieces of code...

Comment: I need some help with understanding of calling lambda expression in recursive function. could you help me with it?

Comment: Your function has an error because it only receives one parameter: a list. But in the recursive call you are trying to pass 2 parameters: a lambda function and a list. Naturally it does not compile. The second example works well. What is it you are trying to do? Are you trying to recreate the "example" without the lambda called `cont`?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to recreate the example. thank for your answer! I'm supposed something like it...

Comment: Continuation style recursion can be tricky to understand. In this case, just think about it like this: the lambda gets called at the very end. BTW, You do not  need the identity lambda `(fun z -> z)` it doesn't do anything. It is needed in the example because something must be passed as a first parameter, but not in your function.

Answer (score 0):

I found it...

```
let rec split = function
  | x :: y :: xs -> let (xs1, xs2) = split xs in (x :: xs1, y :: xs2)
  | [x] -> ([x], [])
  | [] -> ([],[])
// let res = split [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
// printfn "%A" res
```